# Pushing to history after async action fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I've been struggling with navigating in my application after making an asynchronous call using fetch. This function is triggered by an `onClick`

```
const output = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Endpoint`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.props.login.login.bearerToken}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state.thing1)
            });
console.log(output);
toast.success("Lawyer added");
await this.props.history.push("/home");
```

With this code, the URL is updated to `/home` but the screen is not updated to contain the home component which is at that route. If I remove the call to fetch everything works as I would expect. The behaviour looks very similar to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4924 but I've not been able to fix the problem using `withRouter` nor am I using any pure components or components which implement `shouldComponentUpdate`. How can I update the page location after using fetch in an asynchronous fashion?

This is using connected-react-router, typescript and redux. I've used the history object directly passed in from props in my example but it similarly doesn't work if I use the one from the store.

Update: I am seeing `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` hitting my reducers.

Comment: How about making use of `.then` and `.catch`?

Comment: No, that gives the same behaviour.